# Select a row containing a string in a mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select all rows which contains string `$places` in a colum `ADDRESS`. here is what I coded but it only works when a cell only contains that string if there is other characters it wouldn't work

`$sql = "SELECT *,CONCAT(mapLan,',',mapLon) as LatitudeLongitude FROM  " . $table . " where ADDRESS like '$places' and SIZE between $firstrange and $secondrange";`

For example `$places = "East London"`
It would only select the row in which a cell only store `East London` and would leave alone the cells with `Old Street, East London`

What I want is to select all those rows which contains `East London` in Column `ADDRESS`

Comment: You have to supply an example for your rows and show which you are want to be returned and what do you don't to get them.

Comment: @sємsєм I want it to return only those rows containing the full string stored in `$places` for example if it's `East London` it shouldn't show rows with only `East` and `London` but with full phrase `East London` - Thanks

Comment: if `$places` is `East London`, the answer I gave you will never return rows that only contain `East` or `London`

Comment: Do not create hypothetical examples if you are having any problem just post the real data, I am sure you will get help.

Comment: @codehx Thanks - I was doing a really stupid mistake the `$places` was an array which held an empty value so while iteration it was returning me all rows without any exception

Comment: great, you finally solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to use the **%** wildcard.

**meaning:**
**%**   *Matches any number of characters, even zero characters*

```
$sql = "SELECT *,CONCAT(mapLan,',',mapLon) as LatitudeLongitude FROM " . $table . " where ADDRESS like '%$places%' and SIZE between $firstrange and $secondrange";
```

[visit this link for detail](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: I have already tried this but it also select the other rows that doesn't exactly contain the required string I just want those rows which contains the exact string stored in `$places`

Comment: @Muhammad No way, I think that `%East London%` should return any row contains `East London`.

Comment: no, it will not return row that do not contain `$places`

Comment: please post your example, for which you are getting wrong rows.

Comment: @codehx I think it's returning all rows contain not only `East London` and also `London` but I only want it to show when there complete phrase in that row

Comment: That is not possible. If `$places = "east london"` than it will only return the rows containing "east london". Check this demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c31ae/1

Comment: i.e It will not return `East Paris`